# Minimum absolute determinant of a regular latin square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, latin-square

It is easy to show that a latin square of size n x n has a determinant, which is
 a multiple of $\large \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$, if n is odd and $\large \frac{n^2(n+1)}{4}$, if n is
 even. This is a lower bound for the absolute value of the determinant, if the matrix
 is regular. But not always can the minimum be attained : For n = 4, the minimum is $80$
 instead of $20$ and for n = 6 , it is $126$ instead of $63$.

My questions :

- For which n does a singular latin square matrix exist ?
- For which n does a latin square matrix with a determinant of 
  the given limit exist ?

  My conjecture for the first question is that n = 1,2,3,5 are the only values
  for which there is no singular latin square matrix.

  My conjecture for the second quesion is that n = 4,6 are the only values for
  which there is no latin square matrix with a determinant fulfilling the given
  limits.

Comment: I enumerated the latin squares upto size 7x7 and approved my conjectures. The least open case is n = 11.

Comment: For each composite n, there is a singular latin-square-matrix with size n x n.