# Determinant of Latin Squares of order prime

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

Is determinant of Latin Squares of order prime always nonzero?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: An interesting question on some levels. Consider this: if any two rows or columns were equal, what does that mean for the determinant of the array/matrix? Since a Latin square forbids this from happening (by definition) does that then imply that the determinant must be non-zero?

Comment: In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886516/minimum-absolute-determinant-of-a-regular-latin-square-matrix) the OP made a comment that seems to imply a counterexample with order $7$.